# Не отображается первый элемент в списке

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-xml

Имеется `recyclerview` и самый простой список в нём. В адаптер передается 14 итемов, от 1 до 14.

Логи говорят, что отображаются все. А значит, тулбар перекрывает первый элемент списка.Чтобы убедиться в этом, я сделал еще одно активити с похожей версткой, там `textView` на `match_parent` в котором в верхнем левом углу имеется текст.

Этот текст не видно в том числе. Прилагаю верстку:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_list_container">

    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

И да, список в фрагменте находится:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_list_container">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: При добавлении `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` к `FrameLayout` что-нибудь изменится?

Comment: @post_zeew да - это помогло. Когда будете писать ответ, можете подробнее описать, что это, за что отвечает, как использовать?

Comment: Постараюсь. *(4 символа)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

К `FrameLayout` добавьте атрибут `app:layout_behavior`:

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

Атрибут `app:layout_behavior` используется родительским компонентом – `CoordinatorLayout` для управления взаимодействиями между представлениями.

В данном случае, значение `"@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` атрибута `app:layout_behavior` компонента `FrameLayout` создает зависимость между скроллом `FrameLayout` и `AppBarLayout` и, в частности, указывает на то, что `FrameLayout` должен быть расположен под `AppBarLayout`.